# Error "Unresolved reference: _root_ide_package_" after changing the package name

Tags: android, android-studio

When I changed my package name and rebuilt the project, Android Studio put before many class names this string `_root_ide_package_.com.example.<myprojectname>`. And I have this error `Unresolved reference: _root_ide_package_`. Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While posting a code example would help, I had a similar issue and resolved it by doing a Replace in Path across the source tree and replaced all instances of `_root_ide_package_.com.example.<myprojectname>.` with nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove anything before the class name, for example:

```
_root_ide_package_.com.<project_name>.APP
```

Remove `_root_ide_package_.com.<project_name>.`